# RegEx/Javascript validation: Don't allow comma as a valid character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing Javascript validation on my number fields.  I'm using RegEx to do this - first time RegEx user.  I need the user to only enter numbers and decimals, but not commas.  (i.e. 3600.00 is okay, but 3,600.00 is not).  I can't figure out how to eliminate the commas as an accepted character.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
                        var filter = /^([0-9])/;

                            if (!filter.test(txtItemAmount.value)) 
                            {
                                msg += "Item amount must be a number.\n";
                                txtItemAmount.focus
                            }
```

Comment: Do you allow `.0`? Or `0.`? I take it there has to be at least one number, so `.` on its own should be illegal, right?

Comment: yes, "." on its own is illegal, adn multiple "."'s would be illegal also.  but it's currency, so it's okay if they do .05 or 0.50, etc.

Comment: Why not just ignore the commas instead of restricting them altogether?

Comment: ignoring the commas would be fine- if that's a better way to do it...not sure how that would look.

Comment: Also- should mention that negative amounts are also acceptable.  i.e. -500.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow decimals less than 1, integers or integers with a decimal part, you can write a reg exp for that-

```
/^(\.\d+)|(\d+(\.\d+)?)$/.test(value)

or you can use parseFloat-

if(parseFloat(value)+''===value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filter should be something like `[0-9. ]+` (here you allow numbers, `.` and space

A better filter would be `[0-9 ]*[ .][0-9 ]*` where you allow `.` only once.

I don't know about regex in javascript, so you may need to protect some characters with `\`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
^(\d+(\.\d*)?)$
```

It looks for one or more digits `(\d+)` and then, for a period followed by 0 or more digits `((\.\d*)?)` . The question mark means that there has to be either 1 or 0 repetitions of the period and more digits part. THe period (.) is a special character in regex, so it has to be escaped, hence the \ before hand.

For more information, you might want to take a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: The OP's comment said `.05` is valid, but this regex doesn't match it.  It *does* match `123.`, which I would call invalid (but the OP didn't mention that one).

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d+\.?|\d*\.\d+)$
```

will allow `1`, `.2`, `3.`, `4.5`, `12345.67890` and so on; it will disallow `1,000`, `0.123,456`, `.` or `1.2.3`.

Answer (score -1):

Using "lookaround," a combo of negative lookbehind and look ahead, you should be able to fail the match if a comma is present:

```
(?<!,)[0-9\.]*(?!,)
```

Comment: Among many other invalid inputs, this will match the `2` in `,123,`.  Lookarounds are a little trickier than you might expect, and they're no use at all in this case.